# Ranger: Add Foxit pdf reader to rifle.conf

Tags: linux, pdf, ranger

I've Zathura as my default pdf viewer which is fine. I've also installed Foxit Reader but it doesn't show up when I try to open any pdf file in ranger with `r` key. I tried adding following line in my `rifle.conf` file:

`ext pdf, has FoxitReader X, flag f = FoxitReader -- "$@"`

I'm able to open any pdf file with `FoxitReader myfile.pdf` command.

But still, I'm not able to see Foxit as an option in ranger! I'm not sure what's wrong with the edit I made to my rifle.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue was in the syntax. I was missing a `,` after `FoxitReader` and `--` was throwing an error. Following line works:

`ext pdf, has FoxitReader, X, flag f = FoxitReader "$@"`